# How to update the Registration Time To Live for an Azure Notification Hub?

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I have a Notification Hub in Azure. After creation the Registration TTL is set to forever. I would like to limit it to 90 days.

I have tried to update the Registration TTL on Azure Portal, Azure CLI and via the C# SDK: NotificationHubCreateOrUpdateParameters() to update the RegistrationTtl without success. It seems to me that this was working few years ago but not now.

Comment: Howdy - this sounds like a bug. Can you use the "Request Assistance" button in the Azure portal to report this bug to us through official channels?

Comment: I think I cant to that with the free tier.

Comment: @DavidPalindrom - Can you take a look into solution provided in the [Q&A thread]( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/877888/index.html) for the similar issue on How to increase the registration time to live for notification hub using C# SDK, I would suggest you to try the solution and do let me know if face any issues.

Comment: Thanks. That works. Actually I have asked that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question because I have found a way to update the RegistrationTtl:

```cs
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString("connectionstring");
NotificationHubDescription hub = namespaceManager.GetNotificationHub("foo");
hub.RegistrationTtl = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
namespaceManager.UpdateNotificationHub(hub);
```

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/push-notification-hub-telemetry-expiry-update/